# ¿Cómo hacer regex que haga match cumpliendo dos condiciones?

Tags: java, regex

Mi problema es que a pesar de haber mirado las diferentes respuestas, sigue sin funcionar para mí.

Quiero que un regex haga match con:

> "Hola (cualquier palabra menos "que") como (cualquier palabra menos
>   "vamos")"

Por ejemplo el regex haría match con:

> Hola Pep como vas

Pero no con:

> Hola que tal como vamos

He probado esto:

```
Hola(?!que)como(?!vamos)
```

Y esto:

```
(?=(Hola(?!que))(?=como(?!vamos))
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar:

```
"Hola (?!que )\w* como (?!vamos)\w*"
```

`\w*` hace referencia a cualquier caracter de palabra, puede reemplaarse por `[[:word:]]*`

Comment: Además te recomiendo [regex101](https://regex101.com/), es una página muy completa con documentación y donde además puedes hacer pruebas unitarias con varias cadenas de prueba y tienen además generadores de código para diferentes lenguajes.

Comment: De acuerdo! Es la que he usado para validar la respuesta :)

Comment: Tiene un pequeño problema, y es que encontraría `Hola queso como xxx`